# Create equally spaced vector excluding last element

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, initialization

I want to create a vector with values from `n` to `m` with a specified space, but without the last value `m`. If I do `v = [n:0.1:m]`, it will include `m` in the vector.

Is there any way to do this? Or I should delete the last element manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this a variety of ways, here are 3:

1. Make the last element one step smaller, this will be the quickest way.

   ```
   v = n:0.1:m-0.1;
   ```
2. Use `setdiff` to exclude the last element

   ```
   v = setdiff( n:0.1:m, m )
   ```
3. Explicitly remove the last element after creation

   ```
   v = n:0.1:m
   v(end) = [];
   ```